# c# , winforms ,datagridview как программно запретить редактирование некоторым столбцам

Tags: c#

Всем привет. В datagridview как программно запретить редактирование некоторым столбцам.( Сам datagridview заполняется DataTable.)

Answer (score 1):

Присвойте свойству [`ReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.readonly%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) значение `true`